# In Openshift, while deploying the application, I am getting this issue

Tags: deployment, openshift, openshift-origin

[image]

An error occurred while starting the deployment.
Reason: cannot trigger a deployment for "pat" because it contains unresolved images

Configuration from Deployment Menu:

[image]

Here are some of the details, like while building the app, it gives pulling image error.

[image]

When it continues to run for long then I am getting out of memory issue also.

> Status: The build pod was killed due to an out-of-memory condition

[image: Status: The build pod was killed due to an out-of-memory condition]

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered similar errors, they got resolved after increasing the resource limits. My `The build pod was killed due to an out-of-memory condition` error was resolved by increasing the memory limits for my buildConfig. You can do it through `BuildConfig` yaml file like below

```
kind: BuildConfig
apiVersion: build.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  annotations:
    openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewBuild
  resourceVersion: '335448879'
  name: appname
  uid: 4a96c329-3e70-4050-a6b8-32add2e219f7
  creationTimestamp: '2024-01-31T06:40:42Z'
  generation: 7
  ....
spec:
  nodeSelector: null
  output:
    to:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: 'appname:latest'
  resources: 
      limits:
          cpu: "100m" 
          memory: "512Mi"
        requests: 
          cpu: "100m"
          memory: "512Mi"
```

or
through the oc command

`oc patch bc/appname --patch '{"spec":{"resources":{"limits":{"memory":"1Gi"}}}}'`